# How to append attribute value of class if it exists in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a particular board game and am having some trouble with finding if an attribute exists in variables "to" and "play"

```
index_error_lst = []

if hasattr(play, 'player_no'):
    index_error_lst.append(play.discard_pile_no)
if hasattr(play, 'player_no'):
    index_error_lst.append(play.player_no)
if hasattr(to, 'discard_pile_no'):
    index_error_lst.append(to.discard_pile_no)
if hasattr(to, 'build_pile_no'):
    index_error_lst.append(to.build_pile_no)
if hasattr(to, 'player_no'):
    index_error_lst.append(to.player_no)
if sorted(index_error_lst)[-1] > 3:
    return 0
```

I feel like this method is a very long and tedious way of checking if an attribute exists in a class. Is there a way to have a for loop check through the attributes and append those that exist and continue for those that aren't?

The last two lines are used to check the index_error_lst and see if any of the numbers in those attributes are larger than 3 (which is the max player count / max card pile number) and return an error.

Thanks!

Comment: the first two `if` have the same condition..! is it typo ?

Comment: If these are custom classes, maybe give them a member function that builds and returns a list of the info. So you could: `index_error_lst = play.get_error_list()`.

Comment: It seems like you may have made some questionable design decisions regarding your classes. I would suggest either editing this question or deleting and asking a new one that includes the skeletons of your classes. The root of the problem is likely in your class design rather than the implementation of this particular method.

Answer (score 0):

How about a functional approach:

```
from itertools import product

# ...

index_error_lst = filter(
                      # Filter out not-found or None values
                      lambda value: value is not None, 

                      map(
                          # Will receive tuple (obj, attr)
                          # Attempt to get the value or fallback to None
                          lambda attr: getattr(attr[0], attr[1], None),

                          # Cartesian product of its arguments
                          product(
                              (play, to), 
                              ('player_no', 'discard_pile_no', 'build_pile_no')
                          )
                      )
                  )

# ...

if any(value > 3 for value in index_error_lst):
    return 0
```